# Rounded conrners problem with my CSS shape

Tags: css

I have a design problem with my CSS form.
I have created a rectangle which, at some rounded corners, when the window is too small or too big, the rounded corners are no longer round ...

My code:

```css
body {
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: #5F960B;
}

.shape1 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 90%;
  height: 70%;
  border-radius: 0% 10% 0% 0%;
  position: relative;
  top: 120px;
  padding: 0;
}

.shape2 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 90%;
  height: 70%;
  border-radius: 0% 0% 10% 0%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  bottom: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape1"></div>
<div class="shape2"></div>
```

Comment: instead of giving it a percentage border-radius, why not give it a pixel one so the "roundness" is always the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tanks to [Pete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1790982/pete):

*instead of giving it a percentage border-radius, why not give it a pixel one so the "roundness" is always the same*